# Rendering Issue in Jetpack Compose - Android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, koin

I am currently working with Jetpack compose, I have Koin for Dependency Injection in my Project.
When I inject viewModel into `@Composable` function, and I observe some data from the Viewmodel, But the issue here is I can't preview my UI, It says render problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: KoinApplication has not been started
at org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.get(GlobalContext.kt:36)
at org.koin.compose.KoinApplicationKt.getKoinContext(KoinApplication.kt:52)
at org.koin.compose.KoinApplicationKt.access$getKoinContext(KoinApplication.kt:1)
at org.koin.compose.KoinApplicationKt.getKoinScope(KoinApplication.kt:86)
```

It throws the above exception in issue panel in Preview screen.

As it says KoinApplication not started, But I have already Initialize my Koin in Application class and defined it in Manifest.

```
    class MainApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MainApplication)
            modules(ApiModule)
            modules(appModule)
        }
    }
}
```

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposeRetrofit"
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    tools:targetApi="31">
```

And this is my compose code,

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ViewForMainScreen(){
    MainScreen()
}

@Composable
fun getApplianceViewModel(): ApplianceViewModel {
    return koinViewModel()
}

@Composable
fun getAddressViewModel(): AddressViewModel {
    return koinViewModel()
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(){
    val addressViewModel = getAddressViewModel()
    val address by addressViewModel.addressApiResponse.observeAsState(initial = null)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { addressViewModel.callAddressApi() },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(40.dp)
                .padding(start = 40.dp, end = 40.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = address?.mailBox ?: "Country")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text(
            text = address?.fullAddress ?: "Full Address",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 40.dp, end = 40.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

What is the issue here! Any way to solve it?

Thanks For your answers in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio doesn't use your Application class to render previews. Therefore, dependency injection doesn't work.

The [suggested workaround](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews#preview-viewmodel) for this is, to create another composable which takes the parameters from the view model.

For example, if you have a screen called `ShoppingCartScreen` in which you inject a view model, create another screen with the name `ShoppingCartScreenContent`. `ShoppingCartScreen` then extracts all the data from the view model and passes it as parameters into `ShoppingCartScreenContent`.

Alternatively both composables can have the same name. They will just differ by their parameter types.

In your case, you can refactor it like this:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(){
    val addressViewModel = getAddressViewModel()
    val address by addressViewModel.addressApiResponse.observeAsState(initial = null)
    val onClick = remember { addressViewModel.callAddressApi() }
    MainScreen(address, onClick)
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(address: Address, onClick: () -> Unit){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = onClick,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(40.dp)
                .padding(start = 40.dp, end = 40.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = address?.mailBox ?: "Country")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text(
            text = address?.fullAddress ?: "Full Address",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 40.dp, end = 40.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun MainScreenPreview(){
    MainScreen(
        address = Address(), // Create some dummy data here
        onClick = {}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alexander Hoffman's answer: "Android Studio doesn't use your Application class to render previews".

But you can just start dedicated context for preview. [More details can be found here.](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-compose/compose#compose-preview-with-koin)

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun MainScreenPreview() {
    KoinApplication(
        application = { modules(ApiModule, appModule) },
        content = { MainScreen() }
    )
}
```